# WPF Newbie: updating textbox value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I bind a class which derived from INotifyPropertyChange to a Datacontext.
after some interaction, a value will be calculated and output property will be updated.
My problem is that the result textbox didn't update at all.

```
public partial class setraSubWpfTolerance : UserControl
{
        public setraFit objSource = new setraFit();
        public setraSubWpfTolerance()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = objSource;

        }
}
```

And the class:

```
public class setraFit : INotifyPropertyChanged
{          
      private readonly CollectionView _BoreSystems;
      public CollectionView BoreSystems
      {
        get { return _BoreSystems; }
      }

      private decimal? _MaxBoreDimension;
      public decimal? MaxBoreDimension 
      {
        get { return _MaxBoreDimension; }
        set
        {
            if (_MaxBoreDimension == value) return;
            _MaxBoreDimension = value;
            onPropertyChanged("MaxBoreDimension");
        }   
      }
      private string _BoreSystem;
      public string BoreSystem
      {
            get { return _BoreSystem; }
            set
            {
                if (_BoreSystem == value) return;
                _BoreSystem = value;
                calcBoreDimension();
                onPropertyChanged("BoreSystem");                
            }
      }
    public setraFit()
    {

        IList<string> listBore = setraStaticTolerance.getBoreList();
        _BoreSystems = new CollectionView(listBore);
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;                
    private void onPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {

        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

        }
    }
    private void calcBoreDimension()
    {
        _MaxBoreDimension = (decimal)100.035;
    }
}
```

Last but not least the XAML

```
    <UserControl x:Class="SetraSubForms.setraSubWpfTolerance"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                 mc:Ignorable="d" 
                 d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="375">    
        <Grid>
<ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="194,10,0,0" Name="BoreSystemComboBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=BoreSystems}" 
                                      SelectedValue="{Binding Path=BoreSystem}"/>
          <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="194,67,0,37" Name="MaxDimBoreTextBox" Width="120" IsReadOnly="False"
                                     Text="{Binding Path=MaxBoreDimension, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </Grid>
    </UserControl>
```

I expected to receive the dummy value of 100.035 after changing the combobox but the textbox did not update. If i run step by step i can see the "MaxBoreDimension" property of setraFit is changed.

What did i do wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help
sittingDuck

Answer (score 1):

Your method is updating the private value, not the Property:

```
private void calcBoreDimension()
{
    _MaxBoreDimension = (decimal)100.035;
}
```

Change to

```
private void calcBoreDimension()
{
    MaxBoreDimension = (decimal)100.035;
}
```

You're doing the same thing in the constructor, which is causing your `calcBoreDimension` method to not run:

```
public setraFit()
{

    IList<string> listBore = setraStaticTolerance.getBoreList();
    _BoreSystems = new CollectionView(listBore);
}
```

should be

```
public setraFit()
{

    IList<string> listBore = setraStaticTolerance.getBoreList();
    BoreSystems = new CollectionView(listBore); //this line!
}
```

When you create properties that point to private fields, you should almost never have to set the private field anywhere other than the property. This is why properties exist- so that whenever you get or set them, you will run the code in the `get` and `set` blocks instead of just retrieving the current value.

Comment: Also, I think that it deserves a comment that you might want to normalize your variable capitalization conventions to MSDN. Usually this is just preference, and I wouldn't normally comment about it, but your issue here was in fact derived from your naming conventions.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the input. But as i said before, i see the value on debug mode. If i extract with setraFit sf = DataContext as SetraFit i can get the value. My Problem is that i cannot see the value in WPF.

Comment: You're doing the same thing in the constructor. edited my answer

Comment: i started with WPF a few months ago, something else you might find useful from a code review standpoint: when binding to a value, you don't have to specify `Path=`. You can say: `Text="{Binding MaxBoreDimension}"` and it knows that MaxBoreDimension is the path. Also, you don't have to specify `Mode=TwoWay` or `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` for a textbox, because those are already set by default (actually it's set to LoseFocus for a textbox, so it's not running the calc after every single character you type)

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!
The key is to initate the PropertyChanged event for the "MaxBoreDimension"

```
public decimal? NominalDimension
        {
            get { return _NominalDimension; }
            set
            {
                if (_NominalDimension == value) return;
                _NominalDimension = value;
                calcBoreDimension();
                onPropertyChanged("NominalDimension");
                onPropertyChanged("MaxBoreDimension");
            }
        }
```

Thanks DLeh for the contribution.